# Responsive Positioning

Tags: css, responsive-design, css-position

I have a div with nested elements A, B & C inside like so that I would like to make responsive:

[image]

If I scale the main div either up or down (make it bigger or smaller) how would I also scale the containing elements and preserve the same spacing. I believe I have to use relative positioning, but I'm unsure of how to use it. I know there's responsive frameworks like bootstrap and foundation, but I would like to know how to do it from scratch with CSS.

Comment: Post your code please

Comment: You'll need to do a bit of Math using `%` values and the most useful value ever: `calc()`. This isn't easy, but doable.

Comment: Maybe this could be helpfull: http://johnstonianera.com/responsive-two-column-layout/

Comment: haven't coded anything yet. I was looking for the best approach of how to do it or some code examples so I can traverse the code and try to pick out the logic.

Comment: Is this something that web developers do all the time or am i making it more complicated than it has to be lol!

Comment: do you mean preserve the same spacing, as in the same number of pixels regardless of outer div size; or preserve as in maintain the same ratio between inner div widths and gaps?

Comment: maintain the same ratio

Comment: how do I do that? From what i understand I don't have a reputation of 15 or higher so it won't let me give an up vote saying this answer was useful. I would like to know how to accept answers that were helpful to me

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to be less demanding on the spacial relationships and allow the objects to just "flow" therein.  It's a no **work solution**, works everywhere and only requires css with non-fixed sizes, aka width:xx%

Comment: Would using % based sizing be the best approach?

Comment: IMO, yes.  The down side is lack of absolute positioning control. Avoid all fixed sizes and positioning.  Then test by shrinking the browser window size to the left and watch the reflowing of the content.  I like it as it is a ZERO loss solution.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `%` units like this:

```css
.w100{ width: 100% }
.w70{ width: 70% }
.w50{ width: 50% }
.parent{ margin-bottom: 20px; border: 5px solid black; background-color: #dfdfdf }
.container{ margin: 2% }
.box{ display: inline-block; padding: 3% 10%; background-color: black; color: white }
.box.a{ margin-left: 5% }
.box.b{ margin-left: 20% }
.box.c{ margin-left: 40% }
```

```html
<div class="parent w100">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="box a">A</div>
    <div class="box b">B</div>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="box c">C</div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="parent w70">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="box a">A</div>
    <div class="box b">B</div>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="box c">C</div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="parent w50">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="box a">A</div>
    <div class="box b">B</div>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="box c">C</div>
  </div>
</div>
```